# With ifstream while loop, how to show an input error and resume at the next line?

Tags: c++, while-loop, ifstream

If my input file started with a letter it will stop the while loop because it cant rewrite `int1`, I know that but how would I be able to detect this and show an error message saying that `workinfile>>int1` did not work and afterwards continue the loop?

```
cin>>filename;
ifstream workingfile(filename);

while (workingfile>>int1>>int2>>string1>>string2) {
    cout<<int1<<int2<<string1<<string2<<endl;
    linenumread++;
}
```

I tried doing but it doesn't work, any help would be appreciated

```
 while (workingfile>>int1>>int2>>string1>>string2) {
    if(!(workingfile>>int1))
    {
       cout<<"Error first value is not an integer"<<endl;
       continue;
    }
    cout<<int1<<int2<<string1<<string2<<endl;
    linenumread++;
}
```

Also would it be possible to detect if it stops reading the strings as well?

The input file would look like this

```
10 10 ab bc
11 11 cd ef
a  
12 12 gh hi
```

I want to to detect when it hits an invalid input, show an error message, and continue with the next line in the file.

Comment: The while loop will stop at any invalid input. The best approach would be to read a complete line using `std::getline()` in the loop condition, and parse the string using `std::istringstream` and check for each value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight It's not really necessary to provide the complete code here. The problem is pretty obvious with the given example. I've seen far worse questions today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this kind of input, it's usually better to read a complete line, and then extract the values from that line.  If the line can't be parsed, you can report a failure for that line, and just continue from the start of the next line.

That would look something like this:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(workingfile, line)) // Read a whole line per cycle
{
    std::istringstream workingline(line); // Create a stream from the line
    // Parse all variables separately from the line's stream
    if(!(workingline>>int1))
    {
       cout<<"Error first value is not an integer"<<endl;
       continue;
    }
    if(!(workingline>>int2)
    {
       cout<<"Error second value is not an integer"<<endl;
       continue;
    }
    // ^^^^ a.s.o. ...
    cout<<int1<<int2<<string1<<string2<<endl;
    linenumread++;
}
```

Comment: I actually tried using the getline method too but I couldn't split them into separate variables, I didn't know about istringstream I'm gonna go look it up thanks

Comment: Hey just wanted to let you know this has helped my project tremendously and I'm just flying through my project, thank you so much for this.